# How to assert whether there are 2 webelements?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

`xpath = //strong[text()='Review the information below, then click "Cancel this Order."']`

**Description:**

1. With the above xpath 2 elements are getting located in firefox using firepath.
2. I  want to assert whether there are 2 elements available in the page.
3. Tried with the below code but it returns 0;   `@Locator(as=As.XPATH,use ="//strong[text()='Review the information below, then click "Cancel this Order.")`

**Code:**

```
public List<PageElement> reviewTextElement;

public int count(){
    int count= reviewTextElement.size();
    return count;
}
```

Comment: it looks like missing closing ']' in xpath..provide HTML code to help you with xpath

Answer (score 0):

Code is returning 0 because of xpath is not identifying the elements. Using escape sequence `\"` surrounding  `Cancel this Order` should solve the problem if the xpath is you have mentioned is correct.

```
@Locator(as=As.XPATH, use ="//strong[text()='Review the information below, then click \"Cancel this Order.\"")
```